# Why do we say "Mah Tovu" in the morning only?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, shacharis-morning-prayer, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Many say the paragraph “Mah Tovu” when entering the synagogue in the morning. See, for example, [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95)  and [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=3146).

> מַה טּבוּ אהָלֶיךָ יַעֲקב מִשְׁכְּנתֶיךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל.  וַאֲנִי בְּרב
>   חַסְדְּךָ אָבא בֵיתֶךָ  אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה אֶל הֵיכַל קָדְשְׁךָ
>   בְּיִרְאָתֶךָ.  ה' אָהַבְתִּי מְעון בֵּיתֶךָ וּמְקום מִשְׁכַּן
>   כְּבודֶךָ.  וַאֲנִי אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה וְאֶכְרָעָה אֶבְרְכָה לִפְנֵי ה'
>   עשִׂי.  וַאֲנִי תְפִלָתִי לְךָ ה' עֵת רָצון  אֱלהִים בְּרָב חַסְדֶּךָ
>   עֲנֵנִי בֶּאֱמֶת יִשְׁעֶךָ.
>
> How great are your tents, O Jacob, your dwelling places, O Israel! As
>   for me, through Your abundant grace, I enter your house to worship
>   with awe in Your sacred place. O Lord, I love the House where you
>   dwell, and the place where your glory tabernacles. I shall prostrate
>   myself and bow; I shall kneel before the Lord my Maker. To You,
>   Eternal One, goes my prayer: may this be a time of your favor. In Your
>   abundant love, O God, answer me with the Truth of Your salvation.

The words do not seem to specify prayer just in the morning. They seem appropriate for mincha and maariv too. Why then are they not suggested for every time one enters a synagogue (or a different synagogue to the one where I prayed in the morning?)

Comment: Are you certain no one says Mah Tovu except in the mornings?

Comment: Please clarify if you mean only the 1st verse or the entire set of verses that you cited.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35844/5275

Comment: @ezra See ^^^^^

Comment: Seems to be difference of opinions on this. But, based on the opinion that restricts it to Shacharit, I suspect that for some reason, the first visit in the day would do the job for the whole day. That reasoning, of course, would beg the question as to what if someone wasn't in shul for Shacharit.

Comment: Reading your 2nd source, the paragraph mentions *Batei Midrash*. Thus, perhaps its inclusion into *Shacahrit* was based on an assumption that either the Bet Knesset and Bet Midrsah was in the same room. (Common then as it is, now) and that people would be studying all day. Or, it covers both places for the remainder of the day, as I surmised, above. One could ask, why doesn't one say this when entering a Bet Midrash to learn?

Comment: I have heard of a minhag to say this every time one enters a synagogue

Comment: @DanF (1) Which verses: by "Mah Tovu" I meant whatever verses one says at Shacharis. (2) Related question - good find. My question in slightly different to the one you quote: I want to know why we only say it in the morning. (3) The other comments you make could be combined to make an answer.

Comment: Speculation: See Bavli Brachot 12b that states that they originally wanted to include all of parshat Balak as part of Kri'at Shema. But, it was eliminated because of *torach tzibbur*. Perhaps, *Ma Tovu* is a remnant of this idea. BTW, perhaps you can help me (and yourself) by viewing the last *Tosfot* on Brachot 12b. He says there's a discussion in *Yerushalmi* but doesn't indicate where.

Comment: @DanF https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%94 17 lines down. Search for בלעם